# using javascript to create a div onclick

Tags: javascript, html

I'm using pure JavaScript to create a new div element when the user clicks on another div.  Here is my JSFiddle.  No errors being reported, but the div is not being created.  Please help.  Thank you so much!

Basically, this is what I have right now:

```
document.getElementByID("text").onclick = function () {
    var ok = true;
};

if (ok === true) {
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.style.backgroundColor = "black";
    div.style.position = "absolute";
    div.style.left = "50px";
    div.style.top = "50px";
}

<div id="text" style="width:20%;height:30px;background-color:blue;"></div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/eMNfd/1/

SOLVED:

Here's my final code:

```
document.getElementById("text").onclick = function () {
    var div = document.createElement('div');
       div.style.backgroundColor = "black";
       div.style.position = "absolute";
       div.style.left = "50px";
       div.style.top = "50px";
       div.style.height = "10px";
       div.style.width = "10px";

       document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(div);
};
```

Comment: Open this fiddle in Chrome and then hit ctrl+shift+i.  There is an error: Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLDocument> has no method 'getElementByID'

Comment: Also, creating the element isn't enough,  You have to then insert it into the DOM using insertBefore or a similar function http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/dom2.shtml

Comment: The div will get created (provided you fix the scope of `ok` and the typo in `getElementByID`) but you never append it to anything.

Comment: @NathanielJohnson what does that error mean?

Comment: You have a typo(ID should be Id) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementById

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to add the logic for creating the div within the callback function

```
  document.getElementById("text").onclick = function () {

     var ok = true;

     if (ok === true) {
       var div = document.createElement('div');
       div.style.backgroundColor = "black";
       div.style.position = "absolute";
       div.style.left = "50px";
       div.style.top = "50px";

       document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(div); // add it to any dom element you want
    }
};
```

Look at this example

http://jsfiddle.net/eMNfd/21/

I would recommend you to use the addEventListener method to events to a DOM element. In addition, refrain from applying CSS styles via JavaScript; A better solution is to add a class name and create CSS rules for it;

```
var addRect = function(){
   var ok = true;

   if (ok === true) {
      var div = document.createElement('div');

      div.className = 'new-rect';       
      document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(div);
   }
}

document.getElementById("text").addEventListener('click', addRect);
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `document.body`? The code as is doesn't work for me.

Comment: @DanielLisik yes I didn't notice that; Look at the updated answer

Answer (score 1):

Your `ok` variable is local to your `onclick` function. Simply move the `var` declaration outside of the `onclick`:

```
var ok = false;

document.getElementById("text").onclick = function () {
    ok = true;
};

...
```

Also as j08691 commented on this answer: it's `getElementById`, not `getElementByID` (lower case d in ID).

Answer (score 1):

You just created a div element somewhere on a cloud by document.createElement('div'), but you never attached it to the element where you want that div element.
Therefore, you must append that as a child element of some parent element.
Let's take a look at this example

```
var myElement=getElementById("someID");------this will create a handle on a DOM Element
var myNewElement=docment.createElement("div");----Create a div somewhere on the cloud
myElement.appenchild(myNewElement);-----attach/append that newly created element to the
handle
```

I hope this helps.

P.S. As a best practice and to avoid ambiguity, when you create a variable, I recommend not using the name 'div'.

Answer (score 0):

Use appendChild to add it in the DOM somewhere. eg:

```
document.getElementById("text").onclick = function () {

    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.style.height = "200px";
    div.style.backgroundColor = "black";
    document.body.appendChild(div);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/RypAK/

Comment: I see what you did, but how do you make its position absolute?

Comment: You didn't specify that, but you can see how to do that in ppoliani s answer.